# Invoke method with java reflection with list of parameters

Tags: java, reflection

I am currently trying to execute a method via Reflections, but the method parameters are only a list.

```java
List<Object> params = List.of("param1", "param2", 3, "param4");
Method method = getMethod(); //returns the method
AppInstance instance = new AppInstance();
method.invoke(instance, params);
```

The method looks like:

```java
public void myMethod(String param1, String param2, int param3, String param4){
    //some code
}
```

but Java treats them like

```java
public void myMethod(List<Object> params){
    //some code
}
```

The problem is that the length of the parameters varies, the method can have any number of parameters.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Try with `method.invoke(instance, params.toArray());`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```java
Object[] params = new Object[]{"param1", "param2", 3, "param4"};
Method method = getMethod();
AppInstance instance = new AppInstance();
method.invoke(instance, params);
```